# Serving two websites on one VPS

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to serve two Django sites on one VPS (Digital Ocean) using Nginx and Gunicorn.  I have an application called life-cal.  When I type www.thelifecal.com into my browser address bar, I get exactly the response I am looking for and the Django app is served.  However, when I just type thelifecal.com (no www.) I get the "Welcome to Nginx" page displayed.

I used the following two tutorials to set up my server:
https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/cfa565b879ff1458dba08f423cb01d71#copy-this-code-paste-it-in-and-save
https://medium.com/@caterinadmitrieva/serving-multiple-django-apps-on-second-level-domains-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-a4a14804174c

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/life-cal
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 167.71.116.21 thelifecal.com www.thelifecal.com;

        location = /favicon.ico { 
           access_log off; log_not_found   off; 
            }
        location /static {
           root /home/keegadmin/pyapps/life_cal; 

            }

        location / {
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_pass http://unix:/run/life-cal.sock;
           }

      }
```

And a screenshot form namecheap:
[image: namecheap screenshot]

Comment: Maybe the "Host" should be `www.thelifecal.com` in cname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too eager.  Just had to wait for everything to update and clear the browser history + cache.